# Teamcity - multiple build configurations

Tags: teamcity

I am quite new to TeamCity, and have been playing around with it for a few days.  My Visual Studio solution has the following projects:

- SharedComponents: These are shared entities & exception classes used by other projects
- DAL
- DAL.Tests: Unit tests for DAL
- BLL
- BLL.Tests: Unit tests for BLL
- Web: ASP.NET MVC3 project

At the moment I have a build configuration set up that will compile the solution and run all the tests as soon as a change is checked in to SVN.  This is fine, however there are some cases I wouldn't want this to happen:

- if the change is only made to the Web project, only that project should be rebuilt
- if the change is to the BLL, then BLL, BLL.Tests and Web should be rebuilt and BLL.Tests are then executed.

What would be the best way to set up the above scenario.  I would be very grateful if you could assist.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split your build configuration to few:

1. DAL - Triggers on changes in DAL and DAL.Test, build them using msbuild and run tests.
2. BLL - the same like for DAL.
3. Web - Triggers on changes in Web project and rebuild it.

For each you should configure checkout path using 'Trigger rules' of VCS trigger. 
Add to 2nd configuration 'Finish trigger' which depends on 1st configuration and the same for 3rd configuration depending on 2nd. So if you push changes related to Dal, it will build all configurations in order DAL -> BLL -> Web. If you have changes only in BLL, chain will be BLL -> Web, and Web changes will trigger only one Web build.

Comment: Thanks very much.  It works like a charm!! I've also added VCS checkout rules to each build so that only the changes relevant to each project are detected and downloaded